# NullPointerException when creating new JAXBContext instance in Java

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a class that will output my objects to XML and vice versa. My method for doing so uses JAXB, with try/catch.

When I run the program i get the error:

```
New Drawing object could not me instaned.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at se.miun.vife1700.dt062g.jpaint.FileHandler.saveToXML(FileHandler.java:21)
at se.miun.vife1700.dt062g.jpaint.Main.testDrawing(Main.java:53)
at se.miun.vife1700.dt062g.jpaint.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

It seems to be that i have to  write JAXBContext context = null; before the try catch. But how do i do this in a different way? When i cast an exception, won't the program keep being executed? I am new to JAVA and especially exceptions.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
    import javax.xml.bind.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Objects;


public class FileHandler {

    public static void saveToXML (Drawing drawing, String fileName) {

        JAXBContext context = null;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Drawing.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.err.print("New Drawing object could not be instanced.");
        }
        Marshaller marshaller = null;
        try {
            marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.err.print("Could not create a Marshaller");
        }

        try {
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        } catch (PropertyException e) {
            System.err.print("A problem occurred when setting output format");
        }

        if(Objects.equals(".xml", fileName.substring(fileName.length() - 4))) {

            try {
                marshaller.marshal(drawing, new File(fileName));
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                System.err.print("An error occurred when saving to file.");
            }
        }
        else {

            fileName += ".xml";
            try {
                marshaller.marshal(drawing, new File(fileName));
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                System.err.print("An error occurred when saving to file.");
            }
        }

    }


    public static Drawing loadFromXML(String fileName){

        Drawing drawing = null;
        JAXBContext context = null;
        try {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Drawing.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.err.print("New Drawing object could not be instanced.");
        }
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = null;
        try {
            unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.err.print("Could not create a Unmarshaller");
        }

        try {
            drawing = (Drawing) unmarshaller.unmarshal(
                    new File(fileName)
            );
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.err.print("An error occurred when loading from file.");
        }

        return drawing;
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line is `FileHandler.java:21`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels      marshaller = context.createMarshaller(); is line 21

Answer (score 0):

Your way of doing doesn't make sense. Think about it:

```
    JAXBContext context = null;
    try {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Drawing.class);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        System.err.print("New Drawing object could not be instanced.");
    }
```

If a JAXBException is thrown when trying to create the context, then context keeps its original value: null. So what will happen when executing the next line?

```
    Marshaller marshaller = null;
    try {
        marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        System.err.print("Could not create a Marshaller");
    }
```

This is **guaranteed** to throw a NullPointerException. Trying to use a context that could not be created, and pretending no exception was thrown, doesn't make sense. In addition, this is actually shooting yourself in the foot since, instead of having the actual error message and stack trace in the console, telling you precisely what is wrong, you only have a vague "Could not create a Marshaller", which makes it impossible to know why the marshaller couldn't be created.

This method shouldn't catch the exceptions, because it's unable to handle them correctly. It should simply propagate them. Or at the very least, if you want to isolate the caller from gory XML details, you should rethrow a custom (or other standard) exception:

```
try {
    // all the code here
}
catch (JAXBException e) {
    throw new FileHandlingException("Error while saving file", e);
}
```

This is way better because the caller now knows that the file couldn't be saved and can act accordingly (for example by stopping the program, or asking the user what he would like to do), instead of continuing and acting as if nothing bad happened.

Comment: I have done as in your last advice, all codes after one try, and the catch after those. But the marshaller can't still be created and i get a NullPointer Exception. https://pastebin.com/1xxWPzZi

Comment: No you haven't. You're still returning null instead of throwing an exception from the method. And you still hide the actual error by printing "Error while loading file", making it impossible to know what the actual problem is. Replace `System.err.print("Error while loading file");`by `throw new IllegalStateException(e);`. Do the same in the save method. Then you'll get the actual exception stack trace printed instead of a meaningless NullPointerException.